# Software/Plugin for .mpr/.mph ( German Topo Maps, not ILWIS!)

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, software-recommendations, import

I am looking for an alternative to GlobalMapper, regarding reading .mpr/.mph-raster ( German topo maps, not ILWIS). As far as I know, only Global Mapper can  read this raster-data properly.

Ideally I need a plugin for QGIS, which can handle/import this data-type?

Comment: @Dmitry Baryshnikov,  you probably should have a plugin @_@

Comment: Hi Taras, thanks for your comment. Do you know the name of the plugin?

Comment: Probably related: https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=92002 (in German)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but most of the websites from the debianforum are not available any more. Didn't expect that GlobalMapper is the only software, that can handle .mpr/.mph. Thought that kind of  plugin has been developed so far for QGIS, but obviously not.